# Any working solr suggester example?

Tags: solr, autosuggest

All:

I am using solr 4.10 default configuration now, I wonder if any one can give me a working configuration for suggester part? I tried the example in Solr in Action, but it does not work(I tried this /suggest handler in admin page, keeping other options default only specifying a keyword in q ).

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest"
class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">none</str>
<str name="wt">json</str>
<str name="indent">false</str>
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggestDictionary</str>
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
<str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>


<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">suggestDictionary</str>
<str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst
.FSTLookupFactory</str>
<str name="field">suggest</str>
<float name="threshold">0.</float>
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Thanks